# No identifier specified for entity: content.ContentType

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have two tables, `Content` and `ContentType`

Each content has one content type

each content type might be in many contents.

Here is my model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "content")
public class Content implements Serializable {

public Content() {}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
private long id;

@ManyToOne
private ContentType contentType;

@NotNull
private String title;

//getter/setters }
```

`ContentType` class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "contentType")
public class ContentType implements Serializable {

    public ContentType() {  }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private long id;

    @NotNull
    private String type;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "content")
    private Set<Content> content;
//getter/setters }
```

But i get this exception:

```
No identifier specified for entity: content.ContentType
```

Comment: "I get this exception" ... when I do something. Care to share the code of WHAT you're doing, and the exception+stack trace?

Answer (score 1):

Try making the following change.

`mappedBy` should point to the name of the `ContentType` object in `Content` class.

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "contentType")
private Set<Content> content;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Add `@manyToOne` annotation in `content` table too (with getter/setters)